# Sort array of strings by integer (which is the first character)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am wondering how should be the easy way to solve this problem.

I have an array of strings, something like this:

```
Array [ "15 Some string", "16 Some string", "13 Some string", "11 Some string", "6 Some string", "8 Some string", "12 Some string", "5 Some string", "9 Some string", "10 Some string" ]
```

And I would like to sort it by integer, which is the first character of this array (and will be every time), using **javascript**. My desired output would be:

```
Array [ "16 Some string", "15 Some string", "13 Some string", "12 Some string", "11 Some string", "10 Some string", "9 Some string", "8 Some string", "6 Some string", "5 Some string" ]
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex to get the numbers and after it compare the numbers.

```js
const array = [ "15 Some string", "16 Some string", "13 Some string", "11 Some string", "6 Some string", "8 Some string", "12 Some string", "5 Some string", "9 Some string", "10 Some string" ];

array.sort((a,b) => b.match(/\d+/g) - a.match(/\d+/g));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much. This helped me.

Comment: Are you sure, that you answer only no duplicated questions ?

Answer (score 3):

How about simply parsing the string values to numbers

```js
var array = ["15 Some string", "16 Some string", "13 Some string", "11 Some string", "6 Some string", "8 Some string", "12 Some string", "5 Some string", "9 Some string", "10 Some string"];

array.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b) - parseFloat(a));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match the starting integer value and sort by the delta of it.

```js
function getN(s) {
    return s.match(/^\d+/);
}

var array = ["15 Some string", "16 Some string", "13 Some string", "11 Some string", "6 Some string", "8 Some string", "12 Some string", "5 Some string", "9 Some string", "10 Some string"];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return getN(b) - getN(a);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```